# How to define a ValueHash?

Tags: vala

I try to define a `ValueHash` similar to the `ValueList` example in the Vala tutorial:

```
[Compact]
public class ValueHash : HashTable<string, Value?> {
    [CCode (has_construct_function = false)]
    protected ValueHash ();
}
```

Compiling this with valac 0.22 yields an

```
error: unable to chain up to base constructor requiring arguments
protected ValueHash ();
```

Searching the net I figured a call to the bas() constructor is needed, but how?
Trying out (I know that `null` is not a valid argument here):

```
protected ValueHash () { base(null, null); }
```

yields:

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘g_hash_table_new_full’
protected ValueHash () { base(null, null); }
```

OK, probably need one argument more?

```
protected ValueHash () { base(null, null, null); }
```

yields:

```
error: Too many arguments, method `GLib.HashTable<string,GLib.Value?>'
does not take 3 arguments
protected ValueHash () { base(null, null, null); }
```

I cannot figure out what's going on here. As gobject already defines a `ValueArray` in the GLib namespace, a `ValueHash` would come in handy there, but incidentally this looks to be defined in libsoup-2.4, but I don't want to introduce a dependency on libsoup in my
code.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: `HashTable` has two constructors `HashTable` (with two parameters) and `HashTable.full` (with four parameters), see http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.HashTable

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I am aware of both constructors, their invocation via the base() method however is not obvious to me, but @jku clarified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to chain up to the 2-parameter constructor (or if what you are seeing is really a bug) but I believe calling the 4-parameter version explicitly works in any case:

```
[Compact]
public class ValueHash : HashTable<string, Value?> {
    [CCode (has_construct_function = false)]
    protected ValueHash () {
        base.full (str_hash, str_equal, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this compiles!
From the compiler messages in my case above it was not clear to me that the base.full() syntax is needed - thanks for clarification!